# how to read a data file including "pandas.core.frame, numpy.core.multiarray"

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I met a DF file which is encoded in binary format. But when I open it using Vim, still I can see characters like "pandas.core.frame", "numpy.core.multiarray". So I guess it is related with Python. However I know little about the Python language. Though I have tried using pandas and numpy modules, I failed to read the file. Could you guys give any suggestion on this issue? Thank you in advance. Here is the Dropbox link to the DF file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b22lez3xysvzj7q/flux.df

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like DataFrame stored with [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), use [`read_pickle()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.pickle.read_pickle.html#pandas.io.pickle.read_pickle) to read it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_pickle('flux.df')
```

Comment: it is strange that in my python the name "read_pickle" is not defined. Also i tried "pandas.io.pickle.read_pickle", it hinted "'module' object has no attribute 'pickle'"

Comment: what version of python/pandas do you have?

Comment: python 2.7.3 and pandas is 0.7.0

Comment: is it possible to install Pandas 0.12 for you?

Comment: Many thanks, Roman. As you said, it's the pandas version problem.